# Weird Margin and/or Padding Issues

Tags: html, css

It seems I'm having an issue with either margin or padding... I can't tell which because when I make adjustments to either, it doesn't affect them. Maybe it's neither that's provoking the problem. What I'm referring to is the margin/padding above the title for the card.

[image]

But here is the [original](http://codepen.io/brad/pen/bFHos),  and then here is the [copy](http://codepen.io/brad/pen/dFbIr) that's giving the weird margin/padding issues. I've tried everything from speculating the code for hours upon hours to see what's causing the issue, checking multiple browsers, clearing my cache (which usually solves any issue like this weirdly enough) and rewriting everything but still cannot find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you share your css?

Comment: [link](http://labs.oceanicviewstudios.com/now/main.css)
This is the same CSS on my CodePen.

Comment: `h1 { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webkit browsers add certain styling to html tags

ex:

```
webkit-any(article,aside,nav,section) h1 {
   font-size: 1.5em;
   -webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
   -webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
}
```

All you have to do is "reset" your css.

```
// If you want a "global" reset
* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

or

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Alright! Worked like a charm. I was reading somewhere about "resetting" CSS but never fooled around with it.

Comment: It is the `h1` margin that is causing the issue, so no need to do `*`.